# Find pattern in string with regex -> how to improve my solution

Tags: java, regex

i would like to parse a string and get the `"stringIAmLookingFor"`-part of it, which is surrounded by `"\_"` at the end and the beginning. I'm using a regex to match that and then remove the `"\_"` in the found string. This is working, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach to this problem?

```
String test = "xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\w)*_");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) { // find next match
    String match = m.group();
    match = match.replaceAll("_", "");
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the group you actually want, since you're already using parentheses. You just need to tweak your pattern a bit.

```
String test = "xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\w*)_");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) { // find next match
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Solution (partial)

**Please also check the next section. Don't just read the solution here.**

Just modify your code a bit:

```java
String test = "xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy";

// Make the capturing group capture the text in between (\w*)
// A capturing group is enclosed in (pattern), denoting the part of the
// pattern whose text you want to get separately from the main match.
// Note that there is also non-capturing group (?:pattern), whose text
// you don't need to capture.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\w*)_");

Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) { // find next match

    // The text is in the capturing group numbered 1
    // The numbering is by counting the number of opening
    // parentheses that makes up a capturing group, until
    // the group that you are interested in.
    String match = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

[`Matcher.group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29), without any argument will return the text matched by the whole regex pattern. [`Matcher.group(int group)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) will return the text matched by capturing group with the specified group number.

If you are using Java 7, you can make use of *named capturing group*, which makes the code slightly more readable. The string matched by the capturing group can be accessed with [`Matcher.group(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String test = "xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy";

// (?<name>pattern) is similar to (pattern), just that you attach 
// a name to it
// specialText is not a really good name, please use a more meaningful
// name in your actual code
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(?<specialText>\\w*)_");

Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) { // find next match

    // Access the text captured by the named capturing group
    // using Matcher.group(String name)
    String match = m.group("specialText");
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

### Problem in pattern

Note that `\w` also matches `_`. The pattern you have is ambiguous, and I don't know what your expected output is for the cases where there are more than 2 `_` in the string. And do you want to allow underscore `_` to be part of the output?

Comment: No, there will be no "_" in the searched string. So your solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `group(1)` instead of `group()` because `group()` will get you the entire pattern and not the matching group.

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

Answer (score 0):

```
"xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy".replaceAll("_(\\w)*_", "$1");
```

will replace everything by this group in parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

a simpler regex, no group needed:

```
"(?<=_)[^_]*"
```

if you want it more strict:

```
"(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String s = "xyz_stringIAmLookingFor_zxy".replaceAll(".*_(\\w*)_.*", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
stringIAmLookingFor
```